# Library for audio resampling

Tags: c++, c, audio, embedded, resampling

In an embedded (Windows CE) C++ project, I have to resample an arbitrary sample-rate down (or up) to 44100 Hz.

Is there a free and portable C/C++ library for audio resampling?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This [page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/Free_Resampling_Software.html) lists a bunch of options.

Formatted exert, for the records. Please check out the above link for important details and licence information:

- `libresample` and `sndfile-resample` (from `libsamplerate`) (in the Planet CCRMA Distribution).
- `libsoxr`, the SoX resampler library
- `ssrc` (from Shibatch)
- There is a project combining [`ssrc` and `sox`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/resamplerv/)
- New in 2016 is a Python (Cython) implementation: [resampy](https://github.com/bmcfee/resampy)
- [Brick](http://camil.music.illinois.edu/software/brick/) (on [Github](https://github.com/burnson/Brick)).
- [Smarc](http://audio-smarc.sourceforge.net/), available as a command-line program or C library.
- The [resample](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/gz/resample-1.8.1.tar.gz) software package contains free sampling-rate conversion and filter design utilities written in C.

  - [Older Version](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/gz/resample-1.2.tar.gz) for NeXT Computers.
  - [Original 1983+ source](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/original-source.html) for the PDP KL-10.
- Erik de Castro Lopo's "SecretRabbitCode" [`libsamplerate`](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/)
- [`libresample`](http://ftp.debian.org/pool/main/libr/libresample/) based on `resample-1.7P
- [`libresample4j`](https://github.com/dnault/libresample4j/) is a Java port of `libresample`.
- [Open Source Audio Library Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osalp/) (OSALP) contains a C++ class based on `resample`.
- The [Speex](http://www.speex.org/) speech coder/decoder.
- More at [another large list](http://src.infinitewave.ca/) of implementations and their relative performance.